# In ruamel.yaml, how do I emit a ScalarEvent with the literal string "null"?

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I am using ruamel.yaml to emit a series of events to create a custom YAML file format mixing flow styles.

I've found myself unable to emit a ScalarEvent with the value "null", such that it appears in the YAML file as the string 'null', rather than as the YAML keyword null.

In code form, if I try

```
dumper = yaml.Dumper(out_file,  width=200)
param = 'field'
param_value = 'null'
dumper.emit(yaml.MappingStartEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=True, flow_style=True))
dumper.emit(yaml.ScalarEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=(True, True), value=param))
dumper.emit(yaml.ScalarEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=(True, True), value=param_value))
dumper.emit(yaml.MappingEndEvent())
```

I get

```
field: null
```

whereas I'd like to see

```
field: 'null'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete, but since you set `flow_style=True` on the
mapping event, you did not get the code that you shown, and never going to get the output that you want.

If you want to go this route, then look at the only place in the code
where the `ruamel.yaml` code emits a `ScalarNode`. It is in `serializer.py`:

```
            self.emitter.emit(
                ScalarEvent(
                    alias,
                    node.tag,
                    implicit,
                    node.value,
                    style=node.style,
                    comment=node.comment,
                )
            )
```

From that you pick up that you need to add the `style`
parameter. Further digging will shown this should be a single
characters string, in your case the single quote ("`'`"), to force a single quoted scalar.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml as yaml

dumper = yaml.Dumper(sys.stdout,  width=200)
param = 'field'
param_value = 'null'
dumper.emit(yaml.StreamStartEvent())
dumper.emit(yaml.DocumentStartEvent())
# !!!! changed flow_style in the next line
dumper.emit(yaml.MappingStartEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=True, flow_style=False))
dumper.emit(yaml.ScalarEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=(True, True), value=param))
# added style= in next line
dumper.emit(yaml.ScalarEvent(anchor=None, tag=None, implicit=(True, True), style="'", value=param_value))
dumper.emit(yaml.MappingEndEvent())
dumper.emit(yaml.DocumentEndEvent())
dumper.emit(yaml.StreamEndEvent())
```

which gives what you want:

```
field: 'null'
```

However I think you are making your life way more difficult than necessary. `ruamel.yaml` does
preserve flow-style on round-trip, and you create a functional data structure and dump that
instead of reverting to driving the dumper with events:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
a:
   - field: 'null'
     x: y
   - {field: 'null', x: y}
"""

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
data = yaml.load(yaml_str)
for i in range(2):
    data["a"].append(ruamel.yaml.comments.CommentedMap([("a", "b"), ("c", "d")]))
data["a"][-1].fa.set_flow_style()
yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

this gives:

```
a:
- field: 'null'
  x: y
- {field: 'null', x: y}
- a: b
  c: d
- {a: b, c: d}
```

Comment: Thank you! The ScalarEvent 'style' parameter is exactly what I was looking for, I'm not sure how I didn't find that earlier.

Apologies for the incomplete code - you are correct that my example would not be generated by the code I supplied. However, the style parameter solved my problem none the less.

Comment: Also - that functional data structure method does look far neater than sending consecutive events. I will have to give that a shot.